# Find the tangent to $f(x)$

Tags: derivatives

Find an equation for the tangent line to the function $f(x)=(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})^3$ through the point $(1,8)$.

I really have no idea how to attack this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The slope at $x=1$ is $f'(1)$.
$$f'(x)= 9/2 \sqrt{x} (x^{3/2}+1)^2
->f'(1)=18$$
equation of the line tangent to the $f(x)$ at $(1,8)$:
$$y-y_{0}=f'(1).(x-x_{0})=y-8=18(x-1)$$
so
$$y=18x-10$$.

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line is $f'(1)$, the deriviative of $f$ at $1$. So the line will have equation $y=f'(1)x+c$ for some $c$. The line has to pass through $(1,8)$, so substituting $x=1$ and $y=8$ lets you solve for $c$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT!  THe equation for a line is $$y=mx+b$$  You know $m, x,$ and $y$.....